# Conversion from char data type to float, int or decimal data type in C# is Incorrect

Tags: c#, .net

This is my first time writing codes in C# and I tried converting char data type ('2') to an int, float and decimal data type but I am getting a very awkward and unexpected result and I want to know why?

Here is the code;

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace Practice
{
   public static class Program
   {
      public static void Main()
      {
         int number = (int) '2';
         Console.WriteLine(number);
         Console.Read();
      }
   }
}
```

But instead of returning 2 like I expected, the console returns 50 and **I am very very very confused right now**!

Some please, what's going on?

Comment: The ASCII digit "2" corresponds to the ASCII code 0x32, or decimal "50".  SUGGESTION: if you're certain that the character is an ASCII "digit", then you can safely subtract '0' (0x30) to "convert" it into an integer.

Comment: Alternatively, use [char.GetNumericValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.getnumericvalue?view=net-5.0#System_Char_GetNumericValue_System_Char_)